# iOS8 in-app purchases issue

Tags: ios8, in-app-purchase

I am having problems with in-app purchases in an app that I am building. Everything was working fine, but now I am not able to authenticate the item for sale. Interestingly when I test on a device with iOS8 the problem persists, but when I test on an older iPod that is on iOS 6.1.6 everything works just fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems to be solved .. had to reboot the iPad that I was testing with. Maybe it got confused with me switching back and forth between different users, sandbox mode, etc.